# How and where (it is best) to deploy NodeJs application with RethinkDB

Tags: node.js, heroku, rethinkdb

I have a nodejs application built with of course express, but I am using RethinkDb, due to the nature of my application.

What are some of the best choices to Host my application at and how?
Can heroku be one of them?

Comment: Hosting of the application and hosting of the database are two independent problems. It's irrelevant where/how you host your app, as long as it can connect to the db server. If heroku has rethinkdb add-on, it becomes easier, but you could just as well host the db elsewhere.

Comment: Exactly, Hosting of DB is not dependent on hosting of Application as long is it connects. That's why asking mainly what are some best places to host my rethink db so that it connects somehow according to that service.

Comment: Yet the question is about hosting the application. In any case, this is a recommendation request and is off-topic here.